# android animation game development

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am completely new to game development and I have a requirement to develop a game where I need to animate players on a field . I went through few docs but still have lots of doubts.

1. can I achieve this using `openGL` ES alone. What I understand is
   that `openGL` is part of android sdk, I don't have to do anything
   extra than the actual game coding?
2. I saw some engines like andengine which is given as based on openGL.
   What does that mean and  is it better / easier to use these engines
3. If so is there any engine recommended for animating players on filed
   ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unity 3d. unity can export and generate an apk for android

http://unity3d.com/#mobile-games